# Detect when app is closed, terminated but ignore when the phone is turned off

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to know when someone closes my app (taps the home button) or terminates my app (double tap swipe up) however I do not want to know when the user is using my app and simply turns their phone off because when they turn their phone back on it will still be on my app.

I have tried using the `applicationWillResignActive`, `applicationDidEnterBackground`, `applicationWillTerminate` and registering it in my view controller

```
let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appMovedToBackground), name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
```

These either didn't tell me when my app wasn't the focus or if they did work they also told me when my app was still open just the phone was closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some research the only possible way I found was:

```
func DidUserPressLockButton() -> Bool 
{
    let oldBrightness = UIScreen.main.brightness
    UIScreen.main.brightness = oldBrightness + (oldBrightness <= 0.01 ? (0.01) : (-0.01))
    return oldBrightness != UIScreen.main.brightness
}


func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) 
{
    if (DidUserPressLockButton()) 
    {
        //User pressed lock button
    } 
    else 
    {
        //user pressed home button
}}
```

This method works by seeing if the app can change the brightness however some say this will get rejected by apple because they don't want you to do which makes sense why there isn't a built in function for it however there are apps on the App Store that know how you left the app so there you go

Answer (score 3):

You cannot draw the distinction you are asking to draw. Whether the user clicks the Home button or turns off the screen, your app is deactivated and backgrounded and you are told so — and that is *all* you are told.

However, you do not *need* to draw this distinction. When your app is backgrounded, just do whatever is appropriate. You’ll be told when your app is foregrounded again, even if that is just because the user turned the screen back on.

Comment: Ok so I understand that however what I am trying to do is send a notification to my user when they close my app. Any ideas how I could do that without sending it to them when they are still on my app, with their phone turned off. thanks a lot

Comment: I’d say your best bet is to stop wanting to do that. Take a step back and think about why you want to “send a notification when they close the app”.

Comment: My app is to help users stay focused (revision etc.) and when they are on the app they are 'focused' so when they leave the app I need to tell them they are loosing focus  and to come back (there are incentives and when the user closes the app they are to loose certain items) however people who are revising etc do not want to leave their phone on for hours at a time.

Comment: Well, I’ve told you the limitations. You just have to design within them. If you think Apple is not giving you sufficiently fine grained events to make your app possible, file an enhancement request. I agree they are not providing sufficiently fine grained events! But for now the facts are still the facts.

Comment: haha thanks for the help. Problem is I know this is possible because I have an app downloaded which gives me a notification when I close/background the app but not when I leave the app on and turn my device off.